# How to compile Thingsquare (Contiki-port) for TI MSP430

Tags: msp430, contiki

I need to operate my wireless mesh network on the European ISM band  at 868 MHz. My interest has fallen upon [Contiki-OS](http://www.contiki-os.org), and [Thingsquare Mist](http://thingsquare.com/mist/#platforms) is a Contiki port that supports some of Texas Instruments 868MHz transceivers.

Now, I have successfully finished the simulation in Instant Contiki from [the starting guide](http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html), but I have trouble compiling the example codes from Thingsquare Mist.

When trying to add a mote in the simulation with firmware from

```
thingsquare-mist-1.0.1/platform/mist-exp5438/contiki-exp5438-main.c
```

I get:

```
$ make contiki-exp5438-main.exp5438 TARGET=exp5438
make: *** No rule to make target `contiki-exp5438-main.exp5438'
```

Trying to compile some of the examples states that `ip64-conf.h` is missing from `apps/ip64/`, and renaming the existing file `ip64-conf-example.h` to `ip64-conf.h` in said folder just gives me a lot of compile time errors.

Obviously I am doing some fundamentally wrong here, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

```
make contiki-exp5438-main.exp5438 TARGET=mist-exp5438
```

Answer (score 0):

contiki-exp5438-main.c isn't an application, try building anything from the examples directory instead.

That said, I don't really know what I'm doing and I haven't managed to successfully simulate any Mist applications in Cooja myself, but trying to build anything from the examples directory at least gives you a valid make target

Edit: Oops I didn't read the entire question, I saw now that you already tried that as well. The other answer suggested building for mist-exp5438, but as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894434/missing-platform-conf-h-in-thingsquare-mist-contiki-os) you should use exp1101 or exp1120 instead. Except that the application doesn't fit in ROM for those targets...