# Missing platform-conf.h in Thingsquare Mist (Contiki-OS)

Tags: makefile, msp430, contiki

I cloned the [Contiki-OS](http://www.contiki-os.org) port [Thingsquare mist](https://github.com/errordeveloper/mist/) to work with Texas Instruments EXP430 board. When I run `Hello World` from the respective folder

```
make TARGET=mist-exp5438
```

I get the error that `platform-conf.h` is missing:

```
 In file included from ../../contiki/core/./net/rime/rimeaddr.h:57:0,
from ../../contiki/core/net/rime/rimeaddr.c:45:
../../platform/mist-exp5438/./contiki-conf.h:36:27: fatal error: platform-conf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Does anyone know how to write a `platform-conf.h` file? Trying to just add an empty file in the `../../platform/mist-exp54388` makes finding the file successful, but yields a lot of errors.

Comment: These sound like build errors in Mist regarding the mist-exp5438 platform. Have you tried contacting Thingsquare for support?

Comment: Yep, it seems like they only do commercial support. Weird for something that is open source, but hopefully people at the mailing list can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

That's because exp5438 is not really a platform. The platform is either CC1101 or CC1120, which is a EXP5438 board with CC1101 or CC1120 modules. When you look into the exp1101 and exp1120 directories you will find platform-conf.h files.

```
make TARGET=exp1120
```

seems to makes the code compile. Unfortunately the compiled code seems to be too big or something, I get a `hello-world.exp1120 section '.text' will not fit in region 'rom'` error from the linker.

But well, other platforms seem to compile fine, I tried compiling for CC2538DK with the CodeSourcery toolchain and I don't get any errors. But I also don't have a CC2538DK.